# Slanted loop cuts

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to make some loop cuts in the mesh I'm using to create a house in order to add interior walls to the house.  Every time I try to make a loop cut, it starts rotated across the faces of my mesh rather than straight across the mesh.  Is there any way to keep loop cuts from doing this?

[image]

Comment: loop cut follows the topology of the mesh, in your case just add the loop cut then hit S  Y 0   to aline it on the Y axis

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> buttons and place the loopcut in the location you want, press <kbd>E</kbd> button to make alignment with the side edges and then <kbd>F</kbd> button to change to which side to align. Then you can slide the loop and apply the location with Left Mouth Button.

[image]

[image]

Note: If the model is unwrapped, **Correct UVs** option should be enabled in the **Loop Cut and Slide** operator panel.

[image]

Comment: more people need to know about this.

Answer (score 7):

Just like Chebhou said the loop cuts follow the topology. See examples below:
[image]

What you can do is use the *Knife Tool* instead of loop cuts. Press <kbd>K</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd> and drag the mouse from left to right.
[image]

You may also select the loopcut, position the cursor on it and press <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd>(or<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>, depending on your situation) and then 0.
[image]