# Make curved loop cuts?

Tags: python, rigging

I added these loop cuts to a shrinkwrap I made on my arm, but they're coming off very crude. I wanted them to curve with the other edges instead of going straight down. Is there a way to correct this or do I need to manually move the vertices?

[image: loop cuts]
<sup>*Click to enlarge.*</sup>

Comment: At first sight, these don't look like cuts made with Ctrl-R?

Comment: possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29043/slanted-loop-cuts